# Does Yeoman.js configure stuff for both the client and server?

Tags: node.js, requirejs, yeoman, bower

Just want to be 100% sure about this: Does Yeoman.js configure/helps in building stuff for both the client and server (node.js)?

for example: I saw it reference Require.JS. I take it this would mean it could take care of fetching dependecies on the server (for use in the client) using Bower,  creates a Json-file that is used as input for Require.js on the client so the client knows which files to download?

As an additional step it would probably be possible to throw this through Grunt (some sprockets extension) to minify and concat the javascripts based on some config. Correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright focus is on client-side.

Excellent talk from Paul Irish introducing Yeoman: 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mk-tFn2Ix6g